# Cannot power on new VM's on Host3 since bringing under vCSA6 management. Error: Device 'Bootstrap' is not available

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

We have three ESXi hosts, like so:
Host1 - ESXi 5.1
Host2 - ESXi 5.5 (vCenter Server Appliance 6.0 lives here)
Host3 - ESXi 6.0

I deployed vCSA 6.0 about two weeks ago and now we cannot power-on newly created VM's on Host3. Host 1 and 2 seem to remain uneffected by this issue. The error I get when trying to power-on a new VM is:
***Invalid virtual machine configuration
An error was received from the ESX host while powering on (name of new VM). Device 'Bootstrap' is not available.***

From my research I'm seeing that [this issue can be caused by a locking of the VMX file from a different host](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/523944), other than the host that is hosting the VM on its respective local datastore. As such, I SSH'd into Host3 and ran `vmdkfstools -D` against the effected VMX file, but it returned all zeros for the MAC address of the host that is supposedly locking the file (so perhaps the localhost?)

Lastly, I have disassociated Host3 from vCenter, but the issue persists. I am hoping that a reboot of Host3 will correct the issue, but it's very difficult to time this as we have worldwide operations running 24/7. Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So you have three different versions of ESXi, none of them current and you've JUST deployed a non-current VCSA - are you trying to make life hard for yourself?

Comment: Do you have anything helpful to add...or only condescending rhetorical questions?

Comment: The license is for vCSA 6.0 so that's what I was given to deploy. I was tasked with deploying it and making it work as the old vCenter on Windows was broken. I'm not a decision maker in this company, just a lowly IT-ops guy, alright?

Comment: 6.0 licences work for 6.5 too

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that and I'm not handling the licensing part of the project. I will let the IT director know.

Comment: @Chopper3, We have to fix the issue at hand though, maybe just a host reboot will get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this issue before. Try rebooting the host and see if that resolves the issue.